# Forcing Download via Iframe on mobile

Tags: php, iframe, mobile, download

I know there is a lot of questions on this but i have found nothing mobile specific.

For certain reasons i cannot use php on the 'main' pages, so i have done it via jQuery $.get

It works fine, except when it comes to the download, i used a 1x1 iframe to start the download, which works fine.. except on iphone + galaxy s2 (the only 2 i have tested on atm)

my code on the page being called by the iframe :

```
<?

$email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$code = mysql_escape_string($_GET['code']);

include('xxxxx.php');
mysql_select_db($xxxxx);
$now = strtotime(date('c'));

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `xxxxx` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `code` = '$code'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) { echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Code');</script>"; die; }
$query = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
if(strtotime($query->expires) > $now) {

    $filename = "theused.wav";

    header('Content-type: audio/x-wav');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile('http://www.something.co.uk/xxx/' . $filename);
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Code Expired');</script>"; die;
}
?>
```

The download works fine when directly accessing this page, just not when it opens on an iFrame

Gets even weirder... just tried doing a window.location instead, when connected to wifi it fails and says download unsuccessful, on 3g seems to work fine.

Comment: Is that $filename local to your webserver? Don't use a full url in that case - you're forcing yet another hTTP request to be done, when a simple local file i/o operation is all that's needed.

Comment: I have to use one of the most stupidly put together store-front.  I have to absolute path pretty much everything. Regardless this doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to check if(file_exists($path_to_file)) first, to make sure your absolute path matches your expectations. If that all works out, it also means it can find the file, but the headers don't seem to work for the mobile phones. That might suggest it's not allowing these headers to be set in the mobile browsers.

If that is the case, you might need to look for a different approach.

Comment: When i go directly to the page it seems to work, on an even stranger note it will only mess up the download over wifi (on the download it says <untitled> download unsuccessful)

Yet over 3g it picks up the filename etc

Comment: I don't think that this problem is caused by the connection type (3G or WiFi), I think it's caused by the scope of your website and the different ways you're trying to reach it from your mobile phone.

What I mean is that you might be trying to use a local IP instead of the 3G address you're using (the domain name for instance) which makes difference in the way your code interprets relative paths.